# Should the transponder be set to 2000 then STB or STB then 2000?

Tags: airline-operations, transponder

For Airbus aircraft，after the engines are turned off，we set the transponder squawk code to 2000 and then the mode to STB.

Is it mandatory to set transponder 2000 and then STB？Can we set STB and then 2000? why?

Comment: Unless it is written in the airlines operation handbook or the planes operations manual I'd guess that's a just habit because in STB the transponder does not transmit anything and from your explanation I assume that the time between setting squark 2000 and turning to STB is too short that anybody could react on it.